# FindOne not finding item in array properly discordjs

Tags: arrays, mongodb, discord.js

I am trying to find an item in a user's array of items with his id on discord. I have this

```
        const data = inv.findOne({User: message.author.id})
        if(!data) {
            return message.reply("You own no items. Buy something to trade")
        }
        if(item === 'hat') {
           const itemfound =  data.find({User: message.author.id, Items: 'Hat'})
           if(itemfound) {
               return message.reply("FOund!")
           }
        }
```

But it keeps returning found when I don't have that item in my array of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `inv` is a Model, `inv.findOne(...)` returns a `Query`, and `data.findOne(...)` also returns a `Query`. The `Query` is getting converted to a truthy value in `if(itemfound)` and falsy in `if(!data)`. Adding `await` and `exec()`(optional) statements should fix the issue. Also, `data.find().exec()` returns an array, which is truthy even if it is empty.

```
        const data = inv.findOne({User: message.author.id})
        if(!await data.exec()) {
            return message.reply("You own no items. Buy something to trade")
        }
        if(item === 'hat') {
           const itemfound =  await data.find({User: message.author.id, Items: 'Hat'}).exec()
           if(!itemfound.length) {
               return message.reply("FOund!")
           }
        }
```